# Python API with Requests - how to ignore a null value in JSON?

Tags: python, python-requests, jsonparser

This is part of my code. The API provides a JSON file that includes an empty value (null) in one location. I get *TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable* on the line that appends.
I've read about a number of methods to deal with this (I want my program to just ignore the null value, or replace it with 0 or 'n/a' or whatever, but continue, not break) but they contain insufficient instruction - I still need a lot hand-holding, I'm afraid.

```
import requests
all_data = []
api_url = 'https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements?page={}&limit=25&format=json&api-version=1.2&serviceType=03&year=2017&branch=07'

for page in range(0, 17):
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(page)).json()

    for a in data["data"]["agreements"]:
        all_data.append({**a["attributes"], "link": a["links"]['related']})
print(all_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get` instead of direct access:

```
some_val = json_data.get('host', 'N/A')
```

Here is how you can achieve this in you code:

```
import requests
all_data = []
api_url = 'https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements?page={}&limit=25&format=json&api-version=1.2&serviceType=03&year=2017&branch=07'

for page in range(0, 17):
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(page)).json()

    for a in data["data"]["agreements"]:
        res = a.get('links')
        if res is not None:
            res = res.get('related')
        all_data.append({**a["attributes"], "link": res if res is not None else "N/A"})
print(all_data)
```

Comment: David, thank you, but - sorry - where would I use this in my code? I thought I'm already using get in requests.get...

Comment: get is a method for dict it returns None if the key is not found or you can supply your own default value. See my edit

Comment: Thank you very much - super helpful. I just made a modification - your edit erased the whole row in which the None value occurred, so I added an 'else' argument that changed that value to "N/A" and then I was able to get rid of the second conditional. Now it does exactly what I needed!